# How to set a cookie header with ZAP

Tags: zap

I'm trying to use OWASP Zap to scan my SPA web app, as part of Google's OAuth verification.

I find this tool ridiculously complicated, and cannot understand how to perform an authenticated scan. To authenticate, our app makes a request to our API and obtains a JWT, which is then stored as a cookie.

I don't want to do anything difficult -- I just want to be able to insert a cookie header in each request, with a pre-captured cookie (i.e., I don't want Zap to use the login form to fetch the JWT itself).

I've tried to use the "add-more-headers" script to add the cookie header, but nothing happens.

I know that this is a very broad question, because I don't know what is missing here. Does anyone have a link to a super-simple tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because authentication is, in general, ridiculously complicated. ZAP has to handle all the weird ways apps authenticate. Luckily we do have pretty thorough documentation, including a simple option of just specifying a header to use via env vars. To quote from the docs:

There are 3 of these env vars which are documented on the Desktop User Guide Authentication page and reproduced here for completeness:

```
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE - if this is defined then its value will be added as a header to all of the requests
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER - if this is defined then its value will be used as the header name - if it is not defined then the standard Authorization header will be used
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_SITE - if this is defined then the header will only be included in sites whose name includes its value
```

The env vars are standard operating system env vars so how you will need to set them will depend on your OS and possibly your shell. They need to be set before you start ZAP, they cannot be set once ZAP is already running.

The full auth docs are here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/

Comment: Hi @simon-bennetts . Thanks for your feedback. I actually did set these env vars, but perhaps I missed the requirement to restart Zap. Btw, I'm trying to follow these Google instructions: https://appdefensealliance.dev/casa/tier-2/ast-guide/dynamic-scan. Do you know if the env vars will work in this case of running Zap via a docker image?